# Auto-formatting lambda-functions in Visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, lambda, usability

How to set up Visual studio 2010 so that multi-line lambda-functions will not look ugly, with all that empty space in the left?

```
   dataView.CellFormatting += (s, e) =>
                                           {
                                               if ((e.ColumnIndex == 1)&&((dataView.SelectedCells.Count == 1)))
                                               {    
                                                   var scope = Scope.Instance;    
                                                   var row = dataView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                                                   var variable = row.DataBoundItem as Variable;

                                                   if (scope.Variables.Contains(variable))
                                                   {
                                                       dataView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style.BackColor =
                                                           scope.GetGraph(variable).Color;
                                                   }

                                                   else
                                                   {
                                                       dataView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
                                                   }
                                               }
                                           };
```

Comment: I can't visualize what you're trying to say. Maybe an example snippet (before and after) will help.

Comment: I edited my question. That is what I mean.

Comment: R#? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176429/is-there-a-way-to-mark-up-code-to-tell-resharper-not-to-format-it

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how much white space you consider ugly but one thing you can do to minimize it is hit a carriage return right after the equal. Then you end up with something like this. `

```
   {
        var raw_custs =
            (from customer in GetActive()
             where customer.Name.Contains(name)
             select customer).Take(numberToGet).ToList();
```

I usually hit CTRl-E CTRL-D right after making a change like this to get the document to auto-format (Edit->Advanced->Format Document)

(Just saw your amended post - when I put that in VS and hit return after the +=

```
dataView.CellFormatting +=
    (s, e) =>
    {
        if ((e.ColumnIndex == 1) && ((dataView.SelectedCells.Count == 1)))
        {
            var scope = Scope.Instance;
            var row = dataView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            var variable = row.DataBoundItem as Variable;

            if (scope.Variables.Contains(variable))
            {
                dataView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style.BackColor =
                    scope.GetGraph(variable).Color;
            }

            else
            {
                dataView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, hitting return does help.

Comment: You're welcome, also you can play around with the settings under Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Formatting->Indentation (whew!) I know I have the *Indent open close braces* option unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

Now that's odd — the indentation shouldn't go that far.

Try cutting and pasting it in place and Visual Studio should fix it for you on pasting. This is what I get:

```
dataView.CellFormatting += (s, e) =>
{
    if ((e.ColumnIndex == 1) && ((dataView.SelectedCells.Count == 1)))
    {
        var scope = Scope.Instance;
        var row = dataView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        var variable = row.DataBoundItem as Variable;

        if (scope.Variables.Contains(variable))
        {
            dataView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style.BackColor =
                scope.GetGraph(variable).Color;
        }

        else
        {
            dataView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes, copy pasting works. But it is not very convenient, though.

Comment: I found I had to hit Ctrl-K-D (or Ctrl-E-D) a few times for it to finish formatting the Lambda expressions "Correctly"... it seems to have trouble with them..