# Auto-formatting lambda-functions in Visual-Studio 2017

Tags: c#, lambda, visual-studio-2017, keyboard-shortcuts, code-formatting

How I can auto-format code inside lambda-functions?

I know this question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224235/auto-formatting-lambda-functions-in-visual-studio-2010),

But the solution of the question didn't work in my case ↓ (maybe updated)

```
public SyncTableViewModel()
    {
        LoadCategoryCommand = new Command(o =>
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {

                Task.WaitAll(
                                Task.Run(async () =>
                                {
                                    //....
                                }),
                            Task.Run(async () =>
                            {
                                //....
                            }),
                        Task.Run(async () =>
                        {
                            //....
                        }));
            });
        });
    }
```

I wonder if there's an update to this in Visual Studio 2017 !?

or there is a shortcut to use it

such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> .

Comment: There should visual studio text formatting settings. Where u can specify how each statement behaves

Comment: @Naruto I tried to search for this but I haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts, I found the solution:

**Requirements**: [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/)

in Visual Studio

- Open  **Tools** > **Options** or press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>
- Under **Environment** tab > **Keyboard**
- Search for "**ReformatCode**" and select `Resharper.Resharper_ReformatCode`
- Add a new shortcut for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- **Assign** > **OK**

you have two options

- Choose the code and then press the shortcut
- Press the shortcut and the command will be executed on the entire document

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to mark all the code after lambda expression and then Tab.

Comment: Yes, my friend, I tried this before but
I'm searching about something more speedily 
                             such as `Ctrl+K , Ctrl+D`