# Formatting code into a single line using ReSharper

Tags: c#, resharper, code-formatting

I am having an issue with formatting code with ReSharper.

I have disabled the option for wrapping lines. With this option, the following code will be formatted to a single line. How can I have ReSharper not format the following code?

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CountryEntity, Country>()
 .ForMember(dest => dest.CreatedBy, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.CreatedBy))
 .ForMember(dest => dest.DateCreated, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.DateCreated))
 .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
 .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
 .ForMember(dest => dest.CountryCodeChar2, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.CountryCodeChar2))
 .ForMember(dest => dest.CountryCodeChar3, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.CountryCodeChar3));
```

If I enable line wrapping, the formatted code will come out like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CountryEntity, Country>().ForMember(
  dest => dest.CreatedBy, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.CreatedBy)).ForMember(
    dest => dest.DateCreated, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.DateCreated)).ForMember(
      dest => dest.Id, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.Id)).ForMember(
        dest => dest.Name, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.Name)).ForMember(
          dest => dest.CountryCodeChar2, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.CountryCodeChar2)).ForMember(
            dest => dest.CountryCodeChar3, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.CountryCodeChar3));
```

This formatting is also undesirable.

Comment: I have Resharper 6.1.37.86 with default settings for formatting. I used Resharper's 'Cleanup Code...' functionality with all presets and got just the normal behavior (what you show in the first sample). Are you sure you don't have any other VS extensions that might mess up formatting?

Comment: Is your clean up profile using "Reformat Code" option under the C# section?

Comment: @chafnan Yes, I even tried 'Full Cleanup' which has pretty much everything turned on

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use *Line Breaks and Wrapping* → *Preserve Existing Formatting* → *Keep existing line breaks*.

Comment: The correspondent setting (for C#) is: `<s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/KEEP_USER_LINEBREAKS/@EntryValue">True</s:Boolean>
`

Answer (score 9):

Make sure ReSharper → *Options* → *Code Editing* → *C#* → *Formatting Style* → *Line Breaks and Wrapping* → *"Wrap Long Lines"* is turned ***off***.