# annoying indenting in Visual Studio when editing .aspx files

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

When I am editing VB code inside a .aspx file in Visual Studio 2010, my code is automatically indented in a bizarre way.  I have searched through the options and can't find anything that fixes this.  [I thought unchecking *Pretty listing (reformatting) of code in Text Editor -> Basic -> VB Specific* would for sure do the trick but it didn't]

Example -- here is the beginning of a .aspx page:

```
<%@ Page EnableSessionState="True" Language="VB" Strict="true" %>
<script language="VB" runat="Server">
Dim foo As String
```

If I go to the end of the "Dim foo" line and hit  it will indent.  If I fix the indentation, the next line will do the same thing.

Comment: How is it bizarre.  Can you give us an example?

Answer (score 1):

In my IDE I often use "CTRL K + CTRL D" and VS formats my code really neat. Maybe that might help.

Comment: That does format my code, but it's still indenting more than I want.  I want the code in the <script> tag to be aligned all the way to the left.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737222/turn-off-auto-formatting-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, under the **Tools --> Options** menu item you will find **Text Editor --> Basic --> Tabs**.  The setting under this section will allow you to control the indenting however you would like to.

Enjoy!

Comment: I did this and changed "Indenting" to "None" and it's still happening