# Visual Studio 2012 trying to indent a block of code changes the code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, formatting

When trying to indent a block of code in Visual Studio 2012, by highlighting the code and hitting tab the editor is adding the if expression is true

```
if (true)
{

    ... // mycode block

}
```

I imagine I should be able to turn this off with the option settings in

Tools->Options->C/C++->Formatting

but haven't figured out which one, any ideas?

Comment: [This may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737222/turn-off-auto-formatting-in-visual-studio)

Comment: In my VS2012, highlight code and hitting enter just wipes out the code. Do you have some third-party add-in installed?

Comment: I think he may have meant tab...

Comment: How come hitting Enter causes indentation ? :/

Comment: The indentation for visual studio is CTRL + K, CTRL + F.

Comment: Yes, I meant tab, updated the question to reflect this

Comment: Try look options about code snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was driving me crazy as I noticed it was adding a 'for loop' then I realised it was when I was selecting code with a comment after the last brace, e.g

```
// code

for(...)
{
    // code block
} // for <- culprit
```

would become...

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    // code block

    // original code 
    for(...)
    {
        // for loop code block
    } // for <- culprit

} //
```

if I had } // switch it would delete the code block and enter the below

```
switch (switch_on)
{
default:
    break;
}
```

Still haven't found the option to turn this off, but at least I understand what the editor is trying to do