# VSC | Prevent formatting short js objects?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Is there are way to prevent VSC from formatting short objects?

**After I formatted my code:**

```
let obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}
```

**What I prefer:**

```
let obj = {a: 1, b: 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to disable VSC builtin formatting function and use js-beautify as it has an option not to break short-objects that fits into a single line.

Read more about beutify-js [here](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify)
The feature I'm referring to is [here](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/issues/315)

Comment: Thank you. How can I disable VSC builtin formatting function?

Comment: Go to VSC preferences, search for format and make sure built-in format settings is set for FALSE.

Comment: Check this thread on how to disable formating https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737222/turn-off-auto-formatting-in-visual-studio