# How do I stop Visual Studio 2017 reformatting JavaScript

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have searched and read lots of threads, and it seems there are a lot of people who are having similar issues, but not this specific one.
Like most people, I am very picky about how my code looks.
For some reason, VS2017 has its own opinions.
When I type the following:

```
if (something == somethingelse)
{
```

the very instant I press the key for the curly brace,
Visual Studio reformats everything to:

```
if(something==somethingelse){
```

I can tell you that every formatting checkbox under TextEditor->JavaScript is unchecked. As a matter of fact, I have unchecked basically everything in all the languages.

I don't want ANY "help" from Microsoft. 
I would really like ALL auto-formatting to go away.

Comment: the only thing that the auto formatting is doing wrong is removing the spaces, `if (something == somethingelse) {` is pretty clean

Comment: The other thing it is doing wrong is moving my curly brace. As I said, I don't want ANY formatting. Regardless of who thinks what is clean or not.

Comment: with the exception of the spaces (which im not sure why it removes) it just makes the code clean and easy to read

Answer (score -1):

Javascript formatting can be disabled in Tools → Options → Text Editor → JScript → Formatting.

Comment: Everything is unchecked. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Note - in Visual Studio 2015 this can be found at:
Tools > Options > Text Editor > Basic > Advanced look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737222/turn-off-auto-formatting-in-visual-studio

Comment: I already have "Pretty listing" unchecked.  I have EVERYTHING turned off. This is just another wonderful manner in which Microsoft thinks it knows better than the rest of the world. Maybe I should go back to NetBeans...