# Turning off c# formatting rules (indentation, wrapping, spacing)

Tags: visual-studio-2017, settings

I prefer my own style of code formatting as opposed to Visual Studio's default settings.
[image: visual studio formatting settings]
Curious how I can turn off "Apply all C# formatting rules (indentation, wrapping, spacing)
Wasn't able to find solution reading following post
[Turning off formatting in VS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737222/turn-off-auto-formatting-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Nope, had other things to do