# How to turn off the App.config file auto arrange formatting in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, formatting, app-config, code-formatting

I want to turn off the App.config file auto arrange formatting in visual studio.

Here, I tried with this link [Turn off auto formatting in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737222/turn-off-auto-formatting-in-visual-studio) , But it's not working in App.config file. After changed the settings also still it's arranged the auto format.

Can you please someone suggest me, how to achieve this one.

Thanks,
Chenna.

Comment: Please create minimal project that contains only App.config and see it this still occurs, share what what kind of visual studio you are using and what extension you have got installed. This is not default behavior so I assume you have got some addition settings. Also you can try to reset all settings for visual studio like described here https://www.technipages.com/visual-studio-reset-all-settings

Answer (score 0):

Reset setting for visual studio like described here 
https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/visualstudio/ide/reference/resetsettings-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019.

```
devenv /resetsettings "%USERPROFILE%\MySettings.vssettings"

devenv /resetsettings CSharp
```