# How to turn off auto indent in Visual Studio 2019? (not VISUAL STUDIO CODE)

Tags: visual-studio, tabs, indentation, line-breaks, auto-indent

[image]

I usually use comma <kbd>,</kbd> to set the same variable type like the gif above.

But a problem is when I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> after write second variable, the VS breaks the line automatically.

As a formal Atom user, it's a bit tedious because in Atom it doesn't break the line whatever the indent number is. (My current indent number is 2.)

I changed and tested it all of the options in`Tools > Options > Text Editor > Basic > Tabs`, but none of these turn off the breaking line. Even disabling [pretty listening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737222/turn-off-auto-formatting-in-visual-studio) won't work.

How do I turn off this feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Judging by the glimpse of Intellisense and the fact that Enter auto-formats, it looks like you're editing a JavaScript file.

To disable auto-formatting after hitting Enter, go to `Tools > Options > Text Editor > JavaScript/TypeScript > Formatting > General` and toggle `Format completed line on Enter` to unchecked:

[image]

Comment: Thank you and sorry for late response. It works what I expected. Helps a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer doesn't work in Visual Studio 2019 with Visual Basic. These options on the image aren't even shown in the *Options* for Basic.

However, when the *Pretty listing* option is turned off, this behavior ceases.

[image]