# How to increase line height of an angular source code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I want to read my angular source file after some time then I have irritation due to broken code.
After saving, I want to present like [image: this.]. codes are breaking like [image: this.].
How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: It's auto-formatting the code. There's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Yes, I know. There are noting wrong but I want it all in one line.

Comment: Try: [Turn off auto formatting in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/737222/13552470)